# Polymorphism Inherited Class Properties

Tags: c#, xna, polymorphism

I have a base class called 'Sprite' and also have a bunch of classes inherit from it.  In order to update and draw all the inherited classes (Because I'm using XNA), I add the object created in the Sprite constructor to the list of Sprites I have.

```
//Sprite constructor excerpt
public Sprite()
{
    //After all the setup code
    gameSprites.Add(this);
}

//From another class
for (int i = 0; i < gameSprites.Count; i++)
{
    gameSprites[i].Update(gameTime);
}
```

The problem is that from that loop, I want to have special conditions where if the sprite is a Projectile and it's collided with an NPC, it should remove itself from the list.  I know how to check if that object is a Projectile or NPC-

```
if (gameSprites[i] is Projectile)
if (gameSprites[i] is NPC)
```

The problem is that I cannot use all the properties from the individual classes that inherit from Sprites.  How would I go about doing this?  I am new to Polymorphism, help is appreciated.

One more thing, with this code-

```
if (gameSprites[i] is Projectile)
```

How would I check if that object is NOT a Projectile?  I don't seem to be able to use the not equals operator.  Thanks.

Comment: Borat will say `if (gameSprites[i] is Projectile)` ............ NOT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I check if that object is NOT a Projectile?

Like this :

```
if( !(gameSprites[i] is Projectile))
```

When you know that a game sprite is a projectile, you can cast it, you'll get access to properties specifically built for projectiles :

```
var projectile = gameSprites[i] as Projectile;
```

It returns a value if `gameSprites[i]` is a `Projectile`, otherwise a null value.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
if( variable is type )
```

you could use

```
var instance = variable as type;
if( instance != null ){
   //instance is of Type type
}
```

you can use the object after the test for null as the instance is an object of the correct type saving you a cast

```
if( variable is type ){
  var instance = (type) variable;
}|
```

checking if a variable is not of type has now become trivial:

```
var instance = variable as type;
if( instance == null ){
    // instance is not object of type
}
```

Eric Lippert has an [excellent article](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) on the differences and use cases.

With regards to the other part of your program;

I would not choose to let the sprite add and remove itself to & from the list.

Leave that to the 'user' of the sprite. It will give you more flexibility (add sprites to different lists based on type for instance) and will save you headaches if you want to speed up by going multi-threaded which will happen with almost any game.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check the type of an object and/or perform casts on it, this might hint to polymorphism.

For example to perform the collision in your case, if you have 'Sprite' as your base class, and 'Projectile' and 'NPC' as your derived classes, you can implement an abstract or overridable method 'ApplyCollision' in your 'Sprite' class.

Your derived classes implement this method as needed, and in your code, where you normally perform your type check, you just call 'gameSprites[i].ApplyCollision()'.